# .htaccess redirect to a subdirectory for a specific web address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I require some guidance with redirects please:

I have two WordPress installations on one hosting - one each in a separate sub-directory.

I was able to get the control panel to set up redirects for each domain, so that - for example:

- `www.domain1.com` redirected to `www.domain1.com/d-one/`

and

- `www.domain2.com` redirected to `www.domain2.com/d-two/`

Which works fine - I'm not too bothered that the path contains a subdirectory (I assume I can't hide it).

However, for convenience of the visitors, I would like to set up redirects so that for example:

- `www.domain1.com/contact` redirects to `www.domain1.com/d-one/contact`

and

- `www.domain2.com/contact` redirects to `www.domain2.com/d-two/contact`

... the redirect knows which domain is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as no-one was in any hurry to help :( , I did my own bit of digging elsewhere (something I probably should have done earlier if I weren't in such a flap)...

After exhausting all the threads on this site, I found this site:

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

which sorted me right up with this solution under "**multiple domains in one root**":

```
#two domains served from one root..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-one.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/one
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ one/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-two.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^two
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ two/$1 [L]
```

and it also helped me to hide the unwanted subdirectories d-one and d-two.

Loverly jubbly!